# Perl: nmake not found

Tags: perl, makefile, nmake

I've seen two threads similar to my question, neither with an answer that helps me.

I have been given a new laptop running Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64-bit, on which I've installed Active Perl 5 'version 20, subversion 2 (v5.20.2) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread' and Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2015.

Both 'C:\perl64' and 'c:\program files (32)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin' are in my system path [without the single quotes, of course] and if I run nmake on the command line without any arguments and without a makefile in the pwd I get back the following message, definitely indicating that nmake can be found:

> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.23026.0
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> NMAKE : fatal error U1064: MAKEFILE not found and no target specified
>   Stop.

So far, so good. Now, when I run Makefile.PL to start installing a new package, I get the following message:

> It looks like you don't have either nmake.exe or dmake.exe on your
>   PATH, so you will not be able to execute the commands from a Makefile.
>   You can install dmake.exe with the Perl Package Manager by running:
>
> ```
> ppm install dmake
> ```
>
> Checking if your kit is complete... Looks good Generating a
>   dmake-style Makefile

What I don't understand and would like to resolve is why Perl does not see the nmake in my PATH environment? I've installed this same package previously on a number of different machines in the past - the only real variation in any of these has been in the version number of Perl and MSVS release and the bit-version of Perl [in almost all cases I've been working 32-bit instead of 64], but I don't see why either of these would make a difference to Perl not recognizing the MSVS bin directory in my %PATH%

Installing dmake or minGW is not a solution for me: I've already done both and get a series of errors I've never experienced before with this package, so I'd really like to find a solution that would allow me to use nmake - if I still get errors afterwards, I'll work those out when I get to them.

Thanks

Comment: I can't help you with your actual problem, but I installed [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) and it came with a complete development toolchain (compiler, make, etc) that just worked out of the box.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen the recommendations for Strawberry Perl elsewhere when searching for an answer to this, but had not heard of it before. Out of curiosity, I may set up yet another laptop with Strawberry Perl to test with; both as a resolution to this problem as well as to ensure some of my other scripts continue to work as expected (don't see why not, but it's usually  what you don't see that gets you).

Comment: [a bit later...] Strawberry Perl raised more errors than it fixed. Still trying.

Comment: @melpmene, He specifically said he didn't want to use the dmake/mingw chain

Comment: true enough, but I tried anyway.

Comment: Just as update: I spent about an hour with Microsoft Visual Studio Support.  After examining every relevant bit of my environment, and trying what I had not tried (using the MSVS developer shell to run Makefile.PL), they, too, appear to be stumped. 

As an extra step I installed the version of MSVS on the new laptop on an   older machine with AS Perl 5 v12 - no problem there. I'm beginning to suspect the problem lies in the Active State version, but unfortunately I can't download anything older than v18 without shelling out. As previously stated: strawberry perl was no help.

Comment: As luck would have it, Someone had an older install available - v5.8.8. That over came my problem, but, unfortunately, it's 32-bit, and didn't like my 64-bit libraries. Anyway, definitely an ActiveState problem, then.

Answer (score 0):

Edit C:\Perl64\lib\ExtUtils\MakeMaker.pm and add "require Module::Build;" before "require Exporter;" line. The top should now look something like this:

```
# $Id$
package ExtUtils::MakeMaker;

use strict;

BEGIN {require 5.006;}

require Module::Build; # THIS IS ADDED
require Exporter;
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker::Config;
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker::version; # ensure we always have our fake version.pm
use Carp;
use File::Path;
```

That fixed it for me.